# Output Text from File in Reverse Order in C

Tags: c

I was trying to make a code on C, which reads the file.txt, outputs it into console, and then counts rows, words etc, and after all is exporting the content of file.txt to file2.txt but in reverse order.

## The text need to go from this:

> I
> Love
> You

to this:

> ouY
> evoL
> I

What I have in my text.file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e35nR.png)

What i get with my code now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5teLo.png)

Here is my code that's need improvement, because it prints the code how i need but with blank rows, which is not needed. And it needs to be exporting into another file also:

```
        fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_END);
        pos=ftell(fptr);
        i=0;
        while(i<pos)
            {
            i++;
            fseek(fptr,-i,SEEK_END);
            ch=fgetc(fptr);
            printf("%c",ch);
            }
```

there's full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int i, n, j, pos;
    char str[100];
    char fname[20]="mfile.txt";
    char newch[500];
    int wrd=1,charctr=1,rows=1;
    char str1;
    char ch;
    int no_lines = 1;
    int COUNT = 0;


    fptr = fopen(fname,"r"); 
    if(fptr == NULL) 
     { 
        printf(" \n");
        printf("File does not exist or can not be opened."); 
      } 
    else 
        { 
          ch=fgetc(fptr); 
          printf(" \n");
          printf("The content of the file %s are: \n", fname);
          printf(" \n"); 
          while(ch != EOF) 
            { 
                printf("%c",ch); 
                if(ch==' '||ch=='\n')
                    {
                        wrd++; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        charctr++; 
                    }
                if(ch=='\n')
                    {
                        rows++;
                    }
                ch=fgetc(fptr); 
            }

        int wrd1 = wrd - 1;
        float charctr1 = charctr - 1;
        float rows1 = rows;
        float averageSymbol = charctr1 / rows1;

        printf(" \n");
        printf("\nwrd = %d, charctr = %d", wrd, charctr-1);
        printf("\nThe number of rows in the file %s are : %d\n", fname,rows);
        printf("\nThe average amount of symbols in a row is %f\n", averageSymbol);
        printf(" \n");

        }

        fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_END);
        pos=ftell(fptr);
        i=0;
        while(i<pos)
            {
            i++;
            fseek(fptr,-i,SEEK_END);
            ch=fgetc(fptr);
            printf("%c",ch);
            }

    fclose(fptr); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: windows? You need to maybe deal with the crlf chars at the end of each line

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I understand correctly you want to get rid of some of the empty lines which show up in your code and then you want to also write the output of the program (the reversed text) into another file? I am assuming that you want the sentences to be also in the original order.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    FILE *fptr2;
    int i, n, j, pos;
    char str[100];
    char fname[20]="mfile.txt";
    char fname2[20]="outputfile.txt";
    char newch[500];
    int wrd=1,charctr=1,rows=1;
    char str1;
    char ch;
    int no_lines = 1;
    int COUNT = 0;
    fptr2 = fopen(fname2, "w+");
    
    fptr = fopen(fname,"r"); 
    if(fptr == NULL) 
     { 
        printf(" \n");
        printf("File does not exist or can not be opened."); 
      } 
    else 
        { 
          ch=fgetc(fptr); 
          
          printf("The content of the file %s are: \n", fname);
          
          while(ch != EOF) 
            { 
                printf("%c",ch); 
                if(ch==' '||ch=='\n')
                    {
                        wrd++; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        charctr++; 
                    }
                if(ch=='\n')
                    {
                        rows++;
                    }
                ch=fgetc(fptr); 
            }

        int wrd1 = wrd - 1;
        float charctr1 = charctr - 1;
        float rows1 = rows;
        float averageSymbol = charctr1 / rows1;

        
        printf("\nwrd = %d, charctr = %d", wrd, charctr-1);
        printf("\nThe number of rows in the file %s are : %d\n", fname,rows);
        printf("The average amount of symbols in a row is %f\n", averageSymbol);
        

        }

        fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_END);
        pos=ftell(fptr);
        i=0;
        while(i<pos)
            {
            i++;
            fseek(fptr,-i,SEEK_END);
            ch=fgetc(fptr);
            printf("%c",ch);
            fputc(ch,fptr2);
            }

    fclose(fptr); 
    fclose(fptr2); 
    return 0;
}
```

This version first checks if a file called outputfile.txt exists and if no, it creates it. If said file already exists then the program overwrites the stuff which was originally in the file with the new program output (it doesn't clear the file all the way).

Comment: Yeah, it now outputs it, all is fine except one thing. I still get a rows with spaces only, do you know how i can fix it? thanks

Comment: Which input produces empty rows? Can you share your input file please?

Comment: @VasiaPupkin If your input file contains a newline character at the end, then it will also print that character so you will inevitably end up with blank lines if your input file contains a line which has nothing on it since your program prints every line exactly as it is in the original file, but just reversed. Feel free to ask more questions if you want.